# How get objects serialized with actual values instead of {$ref:XX} in JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

I am using WebAPI. my configuration looks like this

```
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.MaxDepth = 1;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Only the first items is displayed, the remaining instance show up as DegreeYear: {$ref:3}
I wan to Show ALL of them, what setting/configuration will allow me to show that. I am
only interested in the First Level, if Degree Year has other child object i don't want them.

```
Items: [{$id:2, OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK:20, OrgSchlDgID_FK:3, DegreeYearID_FK:5, ExamName:1ST Term,…},…]
0: {$id:2, OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK:20, OrgSchlDgID_FK:3, DegreeYearID_FK:5, ExamName:1ST Term,…}
$id: "2"
DegreeYear: {$id:3, DegreeYearID_PK:5, DegreeID_FK:7, Code:1YR, YearNumber:1, Description:1 YR, RowStatusID_FK:1,…}
DegreeYearID_FK: 5
Description: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
ExamMonth: "April"
ExamName: "1ST Term"
OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK: 20
OrgSchlDgID_FK: 3
RowStatu: null
RowStatusID_FK: 1
1: {$id:4, OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK:22, OrgSchlDgID_FK:3, DegreeYearID_FK:5, ExamName:2ND Term,…}
$id: "4"
DegreeYear: {$ref:3}
DegreeYearID_FK: 5
Description: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
ExamMonth: "July"
ExamName: "2ND Term"
OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK: 22
OrgSchlDgID_FK: 3
RowStatu: null
RowStatusID_FK: 1
2: {$id:5, OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK:23, OrgSchlDgID_FK:3, DegreeYearID_FK:5, ExamName:Final, ExamMonth:NOV,…}
$id: "5"
DegreeYear: {$ref:3}
DegreeYearID_FK: 5
Description: "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
ExamMonth: "NOV"
ExamName: "Final"
OrgSchlDgExmSchdlID_PK: 23
OrgSchlDgID_FK: 3
RowStatu: null
RowStatusID_FK: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried `PreserveReferencesHandling.None`?

Comment: Tried that, that setting is crashing down the IIS, An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Comment: Have you tried `PreserveReferencesHandling.None` in combination with `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`?

Comment: The following still result in $id/$ref output... not sure why? jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that line in formatter configuration

```
 [formatter].SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```